# Permission denied when trying to mv on a remote server

Tags: java, unix, filesystems

I made a Java application (which runs on linux) which generates a file in `/tmp/` then move it on a remote disk (handled by Windows/Samba) which is mounted in `/mnt/path/to/dir`.

It works on my local machine but not on the `pre-prod` environment. This well-known exception is thrown :

```
java.nio.file.FileSystemException: /mnt/[...]: Permission denied
at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.translateToIOException(UnixException.java:91) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:102) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:107) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
at sun.nio.fs.UnixCopyFile.copyFile(UnixCopyFile.java:283) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
at sun.nio.fs.UnixCopyFile.move(UnixCopyFile.java:471) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
```

Obviously, I checked the directory owner, checked that the destination directory exists etc.

I also tried to login as the user which launches the application on the remote machine and executed manually the `mv` command : `mv /path/to/source /mnt/path/to/destination`.

> mv: listing attributes of « /path/to/source »: I/O error.

(But the file is actually moved).

What can cause this `Permission denied`?

**Note :** I would fix this by replacing the "move" with a "copy + delete" but I would still be interested in konwing why the move fails.

Comment: You'll need to set the permissions on the remote server.

Comment: @Stultuske I don't think so because executing manually the command works.

Comment: executing manually, you are logged in on the server. that is very different compared to trying to manipulate files on the server from a remote application.

Comment: @Stultuske I was logged on the server which launches the application. Nevertheless, when I executed the command manually, I did not use the path that the application really uses. Now, I get a better error message but still cannot understand what it means. Edited the question.